# COUNT FUNCTION where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

The following query with give me three columns and rows that represent each company_name.  A column NR_OF_MEMBER will give me how many member join that company.

```
  SELECT COMPANY_NAME, ENROLLMENT_FEE, 
         COUNT(COMPANY_NAME) AS NR_OF_MEMBER 
    FROM COMPANY
GROUP BY COMPANY_NAME, ENROLLMENT_FEE
ORDER BY NR_OF_MEMBER DESC;
```

However, I just want to display the company and its enrollment fee, which has the most number of member.  So I did the following by adding a where clause:

```
  SELECT COMPANY_NAME, ENROLLMENT_FEE, 
         COUNT(COMPANY_NAME) AS NR_OF_MEMBER
    FROM COMPANY
GROUP BY COMPANY_NAME, ENROLLMENT_FEE
ORDER BY NR_OF_MEMBER DESC
   WHERE NR_OF_MEMBER = MAX(NR_OF_MEMBER);
```

But it said invalid identifier for **NR_OF_MEMBER**.

I just need to have one row, that only list the company with the most enrollee.

Please help.  Thanks.

Comment: What database are you actually using?  You've tagged this for Oracle and MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the one row with the biggest value by using `ORDER BY` and some mechanism for getting only one row.  In MySQL, this would be:

```
SELECT COMPANY_NAME, ENROLLMENT_FEE, COUNT(COMPANY_NAME) AS NR_OF_MEMBER
FROM COMPANY
GROUP BY COMPANY_NAME, ENROLLMENT_FEE
ORDER BY NR_OF_MEMBER DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Oracle would have a slightly different syntax.  In Oracle 12+, you can use the ANSI standard `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` instead of `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Gordon:  You got it right on the spot.  A similar question:  instead of just fetching the row with the most member, how do I fetch the row that have 2 or more members.  In this case,  it might be the first several rows or none of the rows.  Thanks.

Comment: @KEVIN, that is even easier, just use `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2` after the `GROUP BY` (`HAVING` is to groups what `WHERE` is to rows).

Answer (score 0):

SQL statements have to follow a certain order. You certainly can't have a `WHERE` clause following an `ORDER BY` (or a `GROUP BY` for that matter). Here is one way to do this in Oracle:

```
SELECT company_name, enrollment_fee, nr_of_member
     , RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY nr_of_member DESC ) AS rn
  FROM (
    SELECT company_name, enrollment_fee, COUNT(*) AS nr_of_member
      FROM company
     GROUP BY company_name, enrollment_fee
) WHERE rn = 1;
```

If you want only one row, instead of all rows having the minimum `nr_of_member`, use `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of `RANK()`.